# how to email the output file attachment of the shell script thru python script using cron automatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, python-requests

I have 2 scripts ( 1 is run the shell script and 1 is python script to send an email). Now I want to send the output of the file attachment thru python automatically using cron...

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Karthik,  Be clear when you asking question like, what you have tried and what your code looks like and what is now expected which is not working etc. I have just posted an answer based on what i understood.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of python to send an e-mail :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os
import smtplib

############ File comparison & sendmail part starts here ########
def ps_Mail():
    filename = "/tmp/ps_msg"  # this is your file path you want to sent
    filename = open(filename)
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
        mailp = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['To'] = "user@example.com"
        msg['Subject'] = "My Test E-mail"
        msg['From'] = "some_user@example.com"
        msg1 = MIMEText(filename.read(),  'text')
        msg.attach(msg1)
        mailp.communicate(msg.as_string())
ps_Mail()
```

ABout setting cronjob try as below:

a) if its a shell script then run it like below.., edit the  `crontab` with `-e` argument

```
$ crontab -e
*/30 * * * * /home/script/myfile.sh
```

save the file and you are dine..

b) if its python & you want to run this script every 30 minutes.

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/python script.py
```